# Uploading file to multiple servers?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm creating an image uploader which will give the user an option to upload file to a different server than which the script is hosted on.

Is making an FTP connection from the script server to the target uploading server the only way to do this ?

Correct me if im wrong, but would the path of the file look like this ?

User computer (file) ---> script server ----> target server

Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: That rather depends what code you can deploy / services you can run on the target.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to do this ?

Apart from uploading it twice from the user's computer, I don't think there is.

There's [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Exchange_Protocol) but it is usually disabled on shared hosting in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

In a specialized environment, you could do something with IP multicast, but it's unlikely to work in general.

Answer (score 0):

[cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) supports FTP. You should be able to connect to your FTP servers and [upload the file](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/tutorial-ftp-upload-via-curl/).